# Problema imprimiendo listas después de asignar valores

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Lo que sucede es que al llamar a la función `rand` llena las listas  `availableparking` y `unavailableparking` sin embargo en la función `zonaA` solo imprime  `availableparking` y `unavailableparking` lo lee como si no tuviera ningún valor, quisiera saber como mantener los valores de la función `rand` en la lista `unavailableparking`.

```
import random as rnd
    
    availableparking=[]
    unavailableparking=[]
    
    
    def rand(zonaA):
        
        rnd.shuffle(zonaA)
        num = rnd.randint(3,5)
        unavailableparking=list(zonaA)
        for x in range(num):
            a=rnd.choice(unavailableparking)
            index=zonaA.index(a)
            place=unavailableparking.pop(index)
            availableparking.append(place)   
        print("\n Lugares no ",*unavailableparking, "\n")
        if not unavailableparking:
            print("Its empty")
        
    def zonaA():
        zonaA=[]
        for g in range (20):
            if g<20:
                zonaA.append("A{}".format(g+1))
            
        print("\n ")
        print_board(zonaA)
        print("\n Estos son los lugares disponibles: ")
        rand(zonaA)
        availableparking.sort()
        print(*availableparking)
        print("\n Estos son los lugares NO disponibles: ")
        unavailableparking.sort()
        print(*unavailableparking)
        if not unavailableparking:
            print("Its empty")
        
    def print_board(zonaA):
        
        matrix = [ zonaA[i:i+4] for i in range(0,len(zonaA),4)]
        for l in matrix:
            print(l)
    zonaA()
```

[image: Como pueden ver sale que no hay nada en la lista unavailableparking]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las listas `availableparking` y `unavailableparking` son variables globales.

Si quieres **asignar** a una variable global dentro de una función, tienes que declararla como `global`

```
def rand(zonaA):
    
    global unavailableparking

    rnd.shuffle(zonaA)
    num = rnd.randint(3,5)
    unavailableparking=list(zonaA)
```

Ojo con la diferencia entre **asignar** y **modificar**.

Cuando haces

```
unavailableparking=list(zonaA)
```

estás **asignando** a la variable, estás **creando** una nueva lista.

Cuando haces

```
availableparking.append("algo")
```

estás **modificando** la variable, agregando un nuevo elemento a la lista.

La regla es:

1. Si asignas, la variable es local a menos que la hayas declarado `global`.
2. Si modificas, se toma la variable global, a menos que la hayas asignado dentro de la misma función, en cuyo caso la modificación afecta a la variable local.

Este código ilustra los distintos casos:

```
lista = ['a']

def f1():
    """
    Asigna a la variable lista (local)
    """
    lista = [1]
    print("f1 =", lista)

def f2():
    """
    Modifica la variable lista (global)
    """
    lista.append(3)
    print("f2 =", lista)

def f3():
    """
    Asigna variable lista (global)
    """
    global lista
    lista = ['x', 'y', 'z']
    print("f3 =", lista)

def f4():
    """
    Modifica variable local
    """
    lista = []
    lista.append(123)
    print("f4 =", lista)

f1()
print("lista (global)", lista)
f2()
print("lista (global)", lista)
f3()
print("lista (global)", lista)
f4()
print("lista (global)", lista)
```

produce:

```
f1 = [1]
lista (global) ['a']
f2 = ['a', 3]
lista (global) ['a', 3]
f3 = ['x', 'y', 'z']
lista (global) ['x', 'y', 'z']
f4 = [123]
lista (global) ['x', 'y', 'z']
```

**Método seguro**

Es mejor siempre declarar `global` las variables globales que vas a usar dentro de la función, como medida de precaución.

Pueden darse los siguientes casos, todos los cuales te van introducir *bugs* difíciles de detectar después, cuando lo que era *implicitamente* `global` pasa a ser `local` sin advertirlo:

1. Mueves la función a otro módulo.
2. Renombras la variable global, sin modificarla dentro de la función.
3. Agregas una instrucción que asigna a la variable antes de usarla.

O, mejor aún, evitar las variables globales y pasarlas como argumento de la función. Eso es 100% seguro y bien claro.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!, ahora comprendo mejor.